# Find a logical expression that is true if `n` is a multiple of `2019` and is not in the interval `(a, b)`

Tags: c++, logical-operators, pseudocode

I had the task of finding a logical expression that would result in `1` if and only if a given number `n` is a multiple of `2019` and is NOT from the interval `(a, b)`.

The textbook gave the following answer and I don't really understand it:

```
a>=n || b<=n && (n%3==0 && n%673==0)
```

The thing between those parantheses I understand to be equivalent to `n%2019==0`, so that's alright. But I don't understand why this works, I mean the `&&` operator has higher priority that the `||` operator, so wouldn't we evaluate

`b<=n && (n%3==0 && n%673==0)`

first and only at the end if `n<=a`? I thought that if I were to do it, I would do it like this:

`(a>=n || b<=n) && (n%3==0 && n%673==0)`

So I just added that extra set of parantheses. Now we would check if the number is not in the interval `(a, b)`, then we would check if it is a multiple of `2019` and then we would 'and' those to answers to get the final answer. This makes sense to me. But I don't understand why they omitted that set of parantheses, why would that still work? Shouldn't we consider that `&&` has higher priority than `||`, so we add an extra set of parantheses? Would it still work? Or is it me that is wrong?

Comment: Right about the (missing) parentheses. The way it's written the condition would be true for all `n <= a` regardless of divisibility by 2019. The other odd thing is why two remainders instead of just `!(n % 2019)`.

Comment: Looks like typo in the textbook - please [edit] post to confirm that you tried this code and it does indeed produces result you expect or what book claims (you can always use repl.it to try stuff out like C version of your code https://repl.it/repls/IvoryGoodnaturedDos )

Comment: even if it were correct, it is unreadable. Always use parentheses to clarify the meaning. I shouldn't have to check the `||` `&&` precedence to understand the expression.

Comment: If it's a nice thick textbook, it might be better used to raise the height of your monitor.

Comment: The futzing around with 3 and 673 instead of their product 2019  is a pointless extra step as well. What is this textbook, so we may avoid it?

Comment: @dxiv The reason they used two remainders instead of one is to complicate things so you have to think more, at least that's the romanticized reason.

Comment: @user207421 It's not in english. The reason they divided with 3 and 673 instead of 2019 is to complicate things so you have to think more about why and if it works. Doesn't make much sense, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Trying it out shows that the expression as written without the extra parentheses doesn't work:

```
bool expr(int n, int a, int b)
{
    return a>=n || b<=n && (n%3==0 && n%673==0);
}
```

`expr(1000, 2000, 2018)` for example evaluates to `true`, even though it is not a multiple of 2019.

As you pointed out, the logical AND operator && has higher precedence than the logical OR operator || ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)), so the expression is equivalent to:

```
a>=n || (b<=n && (n%3==0 && n%673==0))
```

which is always true when `n <= a`, even if it's not a multiple of 2019.

A clearer expression would be:

```
(n % 2019 == 0) && (n <= a || n >= b)
```